# How to force Python (EMCEE) to move exactly between the defined range of prior

Tags: python, python-3.x, emcee

I have written the following code for MCMC using EMCEE Python package

In the `log_prior` function I defined the range of parameters to EMCEE moves between them not outside of them.
But the problem is, in the results I see that for instance `od0` has the value like `0.64` which is not in `0.68 < od0 < 0.70` I have this problem even for `b`.

I wonder how to force the EMCEE to be exactly between the ranges I defined.
The model is very sensitive to values and I just want to explore between  `0.68 < od0 < 0.70` not bigger or smaller than this.

```
def log_prior(H0, od0, c, b, M): 
    if  not 0.68 < od0 < 0.70 and  60 < H0 < 80  and   -20 < M < -18.5 and 0.045 < b < 0.065 :
        #return 0.0
        return -np.inf
    mu = 0.878
    sigma = 0.0004
    return np.log(1.0/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma))-0.5*(c-mu)**2/sigma**2
```

without `Gaussian prior` the code is:

```
 def log_prior(H0, od0, c, b, M): 
        if  0.68 < od0 < 0.70 and  60 < H0 < 80  and   -20 < M < -18.5 and 0.045 < b < 0.065 :
            return 0.0
        return -np.inf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses in your logical statement. 
For example, for `od0 = 0.64`, `H0 = 50`, where the prior should be `-inf`

```
not 0.68 < od0 < 0.70 and  60 < H0 < 80  
>> False
```

so the prior gives a negative log probability, but if you add parentheses:

```
not (0.68 < od0 < 0.70 and  60 < H0 < 80) 
>> True
```

which drives the prior to the correct value of `-inf`

Comment: I will check it and let you know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To get best-fit values of each parameter within their prior range, just put prior range in bracks () i.e.

```
def log_prior(H0, od0, c, b, M): 
    if  (0.68 < od0 < 0.70 and  60 < H0 < 80  and   -20 < M < -18.5 and 0.045 < b < 0.065) :
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf
```

Hope this will work for you. Please let me know further.